# Dataloader map set is being called right after get even if set is not executed in code

Tags: typescript, caching, dataloader

Can someone help me understand why
when calling get, set function is called even if it's not in code?

So here is code:

*main.ts*

```
    console.log('1.New CustomDataloader');
    const core = new CustomDataloader();
    const response = await core.getLoader.load('myKey');
    console.log('3.Response:',response);
```

*CustomDataloader.ts*

```
const getCacheMap = new cacheMap<any>({});


private getResolver = async (keys: readonly string[]): Promise<any[]> => {
    // Just for test purposes return -> null

    return await Promise.all(
      keys.map(async (randomKey) => {
        return null;
      })
    );
  };


public getLoader = new DataLoader<string, any>(this.getResolver, {
    cache: true,
    cacheMap: getCacheMap,
    maxBatchSize: 100,
    batchScheduleFn: (callback: any) => setTimeout(callback, 50),
  });
```

*cacheMap.ts*

```
 import { CacheMap } from 'dataloader';
    import NodeCache, { Options } from 'node-cache';
    //import LRUCache from "lru-cache";
    
  
    export default class cacheMap<V> implements CacheMap<string, Promise<V>> {
      private readonly cache: any;
    
      constructor(options: Options) {
        // Ignore options atm
        this.cache = new NodeCache({
          stdTTL: 5,
          checkperiod: 10,
          errorOnMissing: false,
          useClones: false,
          deleteOnExpire: true,
        });
      }
    
      public get(key: string): Promise<V> | void {
        console.log('2.Get key function is called, key:',key);
        if(this.cache.has(key)){
          return this.cache.get(key);
        }
      }
      public set(key: string, value: Promise<V>): void {
          console.log('[!] Set function is called -but why?');
      }
    
      public delete(key: string): void {
        this.cache.del(key);
      }
    
      public clear(): void {
        this.cache.flushAll();
      }
    }
```

And console log for this is:

```
1.New CustomDataloader                                                                                                                                                                                                
2.Get key function is called, key: myKey                                                                                                                                                                             
[!] Set function is called -but why?                                                                                                                                                                                        
3.Response: null
```

Why it's trying to set something when get is called only?
Tried a lot of things but could not under stand why this is happening and how to solve it.
Only thing that came in my mind is to add flag in cacheMap where on get function you set ignoreSet= true and in set wrap it around with if statement, but thats quickfix not a solution.

any ideas? - Thanks.
*And don't mind any as a type, I'm just playing with code for days and added them while testing.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did some research and found in [GraphQL/Dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/blob/9c0b6b06b3abf49aa794918fc3a7119f81987683/src/index.js#L87) git
that `.load` uses both functions **.get** and **.set**

Code piece from their git

```
// If caching and there is a cache-hit, return cached Promise.
if (cacheMap) {
  var cachedPromise = cacheMap.get(cacheKey);
  if (cachedPromise) {
    var cacheHits = batch.cacheHits || (batch.cacheHits = []);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      cacheHits.push(() => {
        resolve(cachedPromise);
      });
    });
  }
}

// Otherwise, produce a new Promise for this key, and enqueue it to be
// dispatched along with the current batch.
batch.keys.push(key);
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  batch.callbacks.push({ resolve, reject });
});

// If caching, cache this promise.
if (cacheMap) {
  cacheMap.set(cacheKey, promise);
}
```

So this responds to my question